# How to re-use code for two similar COM objects?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, com-interop

I'm messing with two objects from two COM components, however they're basically the same thing with different approach and few different (but technically they're different class)

Say there's object `a` and `b` I'm going to deal with:

```cs
var app = Marshal.GetActiveObject("MotherClassOfA&B");
NamespaceA.A a = app.OpenAsA("random-filepath") ;
NamespaceB.B b = app.OpenAsB("random-filepath") ;
```

I want to access some member of `a` that also available from `b`, but still, they're different class

```cs
public void DoWorkA(NamespaceA.A target){
  DealWith(target.member1);
  Check(target.member2);
  BlahBlah(target.member3);
  ... // many others
}

public void DoWorkB(NamespaceB.B target){
  DealWith(target.member1); 
  Check(target.member2);
  BlahBlah(target.member3);
  ... // many others same as DoWorkA
}
```

Though they have the same name, `typeof target.member1` of `a` is `NamespaceA.someClassA`, while `typeof target.member1` of `b` is `NamespaceB.someClassB`, but they have the same name (for most of the members)

Q: `DoWorkA` and `DoWorkB` are almost the same, is it possible to write a universal method `DoWork` for both `a` and `b`?

---

p.s. I tried `DoWork<T>(T target) where T:A,B`, but it failed to build because the Visual Studio can't tell `target.member1` is calling a `someClassA` or `someClassB`

> Error `member1` is an ambiguous reference between `NamespaceA.someClassA.member1` and `NamespaceB.someClassB .member1`

---

For anyone who wonder, specifically, they're:

`a` is `AutoCAD.AcadDocument`, `b` is `AXDBLib.AxDbDocument`

And there's no class or interface `IDocument` that makes `a is IDocument` and `b is IDocument` both `true`

Comment: Write your own adapter class to abstract over both, or use `dynamic`.

Comment: They are vastly different types.  AxDbDocument is a [winforms] control, a wrapper derived from AxHost take makes it easy to create a GUI.   You *might* get somewhere with its GetOcx() method, returns a reference to the COM object that it wraps.  You have to cast it to one of the interfaces it implements, you'll be lucky if IDocument works.

Comment: @Jeroen I'm not familiar with adapters, could you explain further?

Comment: `interface ISpinFreely { void FreeSpin(); }; class AFreeSpinner : ISpinFreely { A inner; public AFreeSpinner(A inner) { this.inner = inner; } public void FreeSpin() { inner.FreeSpin(); } }` and similarly for `B`. `ISpinFreely` is now the interface for all that spins freely, even if the classes are disparate.

Comment: @Jeron I don't get it, `FreeSpin` is reference to the `member1` in my example? But it returns `void` while I need to access the members of `A`, or `inner` in your snippet, not the methods (`Freespin` if I get it right) of it.

Comment: @Byzod `FreeSpin` would be a reference to, say, your `DealWith` method.  You'd make your own `IDocument` interface and then instead of having separate `DoWorkA()` and `DoWorkB()` methods you could have one method such as `public void DoWork(IDocument document) { document.DealWith(); document.Check(); document.BlahBlah(); }`.  Your classes that implement `IDocument` would then handle accessing `AcadDocument.member1` vs. `AxDbDocument.member1`.

Comment: @BACON So I have to write `IDocument` for `A` & `B`, `IMember1` for `a.member1` & `b.member1`, `IMember2` for `a.member2` & `b.member2`...all hundreds of them? And every sub member I need access like `IMember54_132` for `a.member54.member132` & `b.member54.member132`?

Answer (score 0):

Responding to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162830/how-to-re-use-code-for-two-similar-com-objects#comment91315844_52162830) and building on [@JeroenMostert's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162830/how-to-re-use-code-for-two-similar-com-objects#comment91276749_52162830), you can use one interface for all methods, or one for each method, or anything in between as you see fit.  Let's create one for all methods...

```
interface IDocumentAdapter
{
    bool Member1
    {
        get; set;
    }

    int Member2
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string Member3
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

For each type you are adapting, you'll need a class that implements this interface and wraps a reference to an instance of the adapted type...

```
class AcadDocumentAdapter : IDocumentAdapter
{
    public AcadDocumentAdapter(AutoCAD.AcadDocument document)
    {
        Document = document;
    }

    private AutoCAD.AcadDocument Document
    {
        get;
    }

    public bool Member1
    {
        get => Document.Member1;
        set => Document.Member1 = value;
    }

    public int Member2
    {
        get => Document.Member2;
        set => Document.Member2 = value;
    }

    public string Member3
    {
        get => Document.Member3;
        set => Document.Member3 = value;
    }
}

class AxDbDocumentAdapter : IDocumentAdapter
{
    public AxDbDocumentAdapter(AXDBLib.AxDbDocument document)
    {
        Document = document;
    }

    private AXDBLib.AxDbDocument Document
    {
        get;
    }

    public bool Member1
    {
        get => Document.Member1;
        set => Document.Member1 = value;
    }

    public int Member2
    {
        get => Document.Member2;
        set => Document.Member2 = value;
    }

    public string Member3
    {
        get => Document.Member3;
        set => Document.Member3 = value;
    }
}
```

You then need only a single `DoWork()` method that performs its logic through the `IDocumentAdapter` interface...

```
public void DoWork(IDocumentAdapter documentAdapter)
{
    DealWith(documentAdapter.Member1);
    Check(documentAdapter.Member2);
    BlahBlah(documentAdapter.Member3);
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply write a single `DoWork()` method that takes a [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) parameter...

```
public void DoWork(dynamic target)
{
    DealWith(target.member1);
    Check(target.member2);
    BlahBlah(target.member3);
}
```

The advantage of this is not having to write adapter code for, as you say, hundreds of members, however the downside is you will not be getting any compiler/Intellisense help when using `dynamic` variables because member accesses are not evaluated/checked/bound until run-time.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment, most of `A`'s (or `AcadDocument`) members are not simple types. In your code, `bool Member1` is really `AcadPaperspace member1`,  `int member2` is `AcadDatabase`, etc. Do I need to create `IMember1Adapter`, `IMember2Adapter`..for them? Even more, members of `member1` (`AcadPaperdapce`) are also many non-simple classes.

Comment: That depends if, say, `AcadDocument.member1` and `AxDbDocument.member1` are the same type or have a common ancestor type that is suitably-derived for your needs.  If yes, then you can declare the `Member1` property in your interface using that type.  If not, you would then have to create another interface to adapt that property type like you suggest.

Comment: OK, then maybe I shouldn't treat them as "similar" class, they have nearly nothing in common when it comes to interface designing, only names. I should create two `DoWork` for them, I think that's much easier than creating thousands of adapters since there's only `A` and `B` in working situation, no `C` or `D` or more "similar classes" benifit from the adapters.

Comment: If you look at the code from the [first version of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52213801/1) you'll see I pushed into the interface not the member accesses but the methods called by `DoWork()`; that avoids creating endless adapters but will not eliminate duplicated code, which I think is the point of your question.  It sounds like this would be a good case for using `dynamic`, which will work as long as the types you'll be accessing are all the same "shape".

Comment: Yeah, the only thing they have in common is the "shape", I think you're right